# $watch not being fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I am using code from an [AngularJS implementation of ScrollSpy](https://gist.github.com/alxhill/6886760) ([original article here](http://alxhill.com/blog/articles/angular-scrollspy/)) but have ran into a problem when my navigation is dynamically created, but it does work when the navigation is statically created.

So I have a `scrollSpy` directive that watches a list of `spies`.  The `spies` list is basically a list of the navigational elements it should highlight as the user scrolls through a page.  `spies` are added via an `addSpy` method in the `scrollSpy` controller like so

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.spies = [];
    return this.addSpy = function (spyObj) {
        return $scope.spies.push(spyObj);
    };
},
```

The `addSpy` function always gets called, however when I add the spies dynamically the $watch for that list never gets fired, it does get fired when the navigational items are statically created.

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('spies', function (spies) {
        // I never get called when spies are added dynamically, even 
        // though spies are added to the $scope.spies object in the controller!
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand why the $watch isnt being fired? I tried adding `$scope.$apply` to it but it said it was already inside a digest cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope.$watch('spies', function (spies) {
    // I never get called when spies are added dynamically, even 
    // though spies are added to the $scope.spies object in the controller!
}, true);
```

You have to tack on `,true` at the end as you're not changing the reference, just updating it.